# Markdown Preview in VS Code doesn't disable font ligatures

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I am using the font "Cascadia Code" as my default font in Visual Studio Code. I don't want font ligatures in my editor. By default, `"editor.fontLigatures": false` is set, which means font ligatures are disabled by default in Visual Studio Code, and it works, I see no font ligatures in my code. But the problem is, when I am working on a markdown file, which contains code blocks, the source code doesn't show font ligatures, but when I preview the markdown file, I found font ligatures in the preview. Then I explicitly set `"editor.fontLigatures": false` in my User settings.json. Even then, I see those font ligatures in markdown are still appearing. How do I stop that ?
Changing the font to a font which doesn't support font ligatures doesn't show ligatures in markdown preview, but I want just Cascadia Code. Is changing the font only way ?

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.58.2
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop LTS

Comment: I have this same problem, which they say here is resolved: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1747 Do you still have this problem?